# Server isn't forwarding the message to the client

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm a novice in Java socket communication, I'm trying to connect 3 clients to a server without the use of threads as the number of clients connected to the server will as be 3. I have written a condition in the server to tokenize the received input from the client and send write to the respective stream. But the message isn't reaching the server so I'm not sure whether the client isn't writing to the stream or the server is unable to receive the data. I'm trying to establish a cryptographic protocol between the connected clients for demonstration purposes.

I was using `BufferedReader` and `PrintStream` earlier since I was testing with keyboard input, then I changed to data streams still doesn't seem to work

Here my code at Server.java to forward messages, the control doesn't appear to come to this loop at all(not sure).

```
while(true){
    String recvd=cin2.readLine();
    System.out.println("At server: "+recvd);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(recvd);
    String MsgToSend=st.nextToken();
    String recipient=st.nextToken();

    if(recipient.equalsIgnoreCase("client1")){
        cout2.writeUTF(MsgToSend);
    }
    else if(recipient.equalsIgnoreCase("client2")){
        cout.writeUTF(MsgToSend);
    }
    else if(recipient.equalsIgnoreCase("client3")){
        cout3.writeUTF(MsgToSend);
    }
}
```

Here is my client-side code,

```
while(i==0){
    String s1="A";
    String s2="B";
    String s3="client1";
    String toSend=String.join(" ",s1+s2,s3);
    System.out.println("toSend :"+toSend);
    sout.writeUTF(toSend);
    sout.flush();
    i++;
}
```

Receiving Client,

```
while (true){
    s=sin.readLine();
    System.out.print("Server : "+s+"\n");
}
```

Not sure whether the client is unable to write or the server is unable to read. Any suggestions or solutions to correct the code?

Comment: `without the use of threads` I'd assume this is the problem without seeing more code

Comment: So you've shown the code that never gets executed but not the code where the server is blocking? We obviously can't help you then beyond telling you your problem is in that code.

Comment: `readLnme()` and `writeUTF()` do not interoperate. See the Javadoc. Either send a line or read with `readUTF()`. And you certainly do needs threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The socket navigation logic in your server file seems to be strange as you are manually creating a string with keyword client1 and then tokenizing it for navigation. By this approach your flow would get static and establishment of a protocol gets difficult.

Please see: 
You are sending the data to client 1 by forming the string AB client1, then your server file's first line is using client 2 socket reading. (Sending data from client1 socket to client1 socket, not right).
Please change that to client1 socket reading, use prinln() and readline() to send and read socket data and then check if your flow is fine!
Also, for the protocol flow, you have to send the data to the other two sockets and not to the one that is sending.

For eg: if you are sending the data from client 1 to client 2, as per your approach, you have to for a string AB client2 and send to the server, tokenize it and navigate the flow to client 2.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Areed

Comment: The logic is *not* fine. Errors in it have already been pointed out. A question is not an answer.